# What kind of hypergeometric function is it?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax, special-functions

I found a formula for an integral of a product of three Bessel functions at [The Wolfram Functions Site](http://functions.wolfram.com/03.01.21.0083.01):

[image: Bessel function integral]

I cannot understand what kind of hypergeometric function it is.
The *Mathematica* code given for it is:

```
HypergeometricPFQ[{{(α + λ + μ + ν)/2, (α + λ + μ - ν)/2}, {}, {}},
                  {{}, {λ + 1}, {μ + 1}}, a^2/c^2, b^2/c^2]
```

When I try to evaluate it in *Mathematica* 9, the last argument is highlighted in red and I get an error message:

> HypergeometricPFQ::argrx: HypergeometricPFQ called with 4 arguments; 3 arguments are expected. >>

Comment: It's a Kampé de Fériet function. Unfortunately, *Mathematica* does not yet have support for this multivariate hypergeometric function, so I don't quite understand how they generated that *Mathematica* syntax.

Comment: What version of Mathematica you have?

Comment: In that case, it doesn't seem we'll be seeing more multivariate hypergeometric functions anytime soon. All they have is one of Appell's quartet and arguably Meijer's function.

Comment: @Spawn1701D Several versions, including 9.

Comment: haha. But I'm very curious now. You were just joking I assume.

Comment: @J.M. How did you convert `\[Mu]` to `μ` in the question?

Comment: I knew the Unicode in this case. An easier method would be to type out the $\LaTeX$, wait for MathJax to render the Greeks, and then copy whatever MathJax is displaying.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is [Kampé de Fériet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html), introduced in *Joseph Kampé de Fériet, ["La fonction hypergéométrique."](http://books.google.com/books?id=JObuAAAAMAAJ), Mémorial des sciences mathématiques, Paris, Gauthier-Villars.*

Its definition is given on [Notations](http://functions.wolfram.com/Notations/5/) page:

[image: Kampé de Fériet function]
<sub>(source: [wolfram.com](http://functions.wolfram.com/Notations/5/06/imagetext/0043/text43.gif))</sub>

and, in an alternative form, in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function):

$${}^{p+q}f_{r+s}\left(
\begin{matrix}
a_1,\cdots,a_p\colon b_1,b_1{}';\cdots;b_q,b_q{}'; \\
c_1,\cdots,c_r\colon d_1,d_1{}';\cdots;d_s,d_s{}';
\end{matrix}
x,y\right)=\\
\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a_1)_{m+n}\cdots(a_p)_{m+n}}{(c_1)_{m+n}\cdots(c_r)_{m+n}}\frac{(b_1)_m(b_1{}')_n\cdots(b_q)_m(b_q{}')_n}{(d_1)_m(d_1{}')_n\cdots(d_s)_m(d_s{}')_n}\cdot\frac{x^my^n}{m!n!}.$$

---

In this case the Kampé de Fériet function can be represented as an infinite sum of hypergeometric functions:

$$\begin{align*}
&\int_0^\infty t^{\alpha-1}J_\lambda(a\,t)\,J_\mu(b\,t)\,J_\nu(c\,t)\, dt=\\&\small\pi^{-1}\,2^{\alpha-1}a^\lambda\,b^\mu\,c^{-\alpha-\lambda-\mu}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(\alpha+\lambda+\mu-\nu)\right)\times\\&\small\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma\left(m+\frac{\alpha+\lambda+\mu-\nu}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(m+\frac{\alpha+\lambda+\mu+\nu}{2}\right)\,_2F_1\left(m+\frac{\alpha +\lambda +\mu -\nu}{2},m+\frac{\alpha +\lambda +\mu +\nu}{2};\mu+1;\frac{b^2}{c^2}\right)}{(m!)^2\,\Gamma(m+\lambda+1)}\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^{2m}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 11):

Since your question's been answered, let me tell you about [the handy listing of notations](http://functions.wolfram.com/Notations/) used by the Wolfram Functions site. In particular, if I scroll down to the "F" section of [this page](http://functions.wolfram.com/Notations/5/), you'll see an explanation that you are indeed looking at Kampé de Fériet's function.