# A question concerning a generalization of HypergeometricPFQ

Tags: special-functions

I have been trying to find explicit formulas for the real and imaginary parts of the Wolfram function EllipticK. An interesting formula for the real part of EllipticK evaluated at a complex number is given in the following link.

http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/19/01/0001/

However, I am having difficulty in figuring out exactly what is meant by the strange "hypergeometric-like" notation used in first formula in the above link. We see that the following Mathematica syntax is used to denote this formula.

Re[EllipticK[x + I y]] == (Pi/2) HypergeometricPFQ[{{3/4, 3/4, 5/4, 5/4}, {}, {}}, {{1, 3/2}, {1/2}, {3/2}}, -y^2, x^2] + ((Pi x)/8) HypergeometricPFQ[{{1/4, 1/4, 3/4, 3/4}, {}, {}}, {{1, 1/2}, {1/2}, {1/2}}, -y^2, x^2] /; Element[x, Reals] && Element[y, Reals]

However, inputting the expression

HypergeometricPFQ[{{3/4, 3/4, 5/4, 5/4}, {}, {}}, {{1, 3/2}, {1/2}, {3/2}}, -y^2, x^2]

with Mathematica 11 results in the following error message:

"HypergeometricPFQ::argrx: HypergeometricPFQ called with 4 arguments; 3 arguments are expected."

What exactly is meant by the "generalization" of the HypergeometricPFQ function in the above link? How can the corresponding formula be successfully implemented using Mathematica?

Thank you.

Comment: That's the [Kampé de Fériet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html), which is not yet implemented in *Mathematica*. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25680) is a related question.