# What is this documentation talking about? Re: hyper geometric functions

Tags: special-functions, documentation

I am mucking about with hypergeometric functions and looking at some of the Wolfram identities. In the documentation I found this

http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/20/01/02/0002/

It specifically refers to a function written

$$F^{2\;1\;1}_{2\;0\;1}\left[\begin{matrix}\cdot,\cdot;\cdot;\cdot\\\cdot\cdot;;\cdot\end{matrix}\cdot,\cdot\right]$$

and claims that its input in mathematica is given by (for some parameters)

`HypergeometricPFQ[{{1 + a, 1 + b}, {1}, {1, b}}, {{2, 1 + c}, {}, {1 + b}}, z, z]`

I cannot find the definition of such a function anywhere. Moreover, when I attempt to input said function into Mathematica (version 12) it doesn't recognise the input giving error

`HypergeometricPFQ: HypergeometricPFQ called with 4 arguments; 3 arguments are expected.`

Is this just a deprecated function lying around on the web? Even if so, what is it?

Granted the page is fairly old, but it's still bad form to have that up on the web. And fairly mind-boggling to me not to explain, even just mathematically, what this mystery function is...

EDIT:

To be clear: the function is not the usual HypergeometricPFQ function which I am well aware of and is well documented. It is a unspecified function that appears in past versions of Mathematica to have overloaded the `HypergeometricPFQ` symbolic function name.

Comment: In the `Details` section of the documentation the definition is given.

Comment: @JimB What? Ctrl+F on that page for "Details" draws a blank...

Comment: That page you linked to is dated 2001-10-29. That's pretty old documentation! You'll no doubt get better results using more recent documentation, as for the HypergeometricPFQ function.

Comment: @bills I appreciate that, but mathematical identities don't go out of date! The function is *something*, but there is no equivalent listed in the new documentation. That specific idiom (giving `HypergeometricPFQ` 4 inputs - some of which are themselves lists of lists) is now not valid. Forget, the mathematica aspect - what is that function? Where in the modern documentation is that function described? I am at a loss.

Comment: Mathematical identities may not go out of date, but software implementations do, as evidenced by this question! But maybe you'll be lucky and someone from Wolfram will remember how they implemented this 20 years ago.

Comment: @bills `HypergeometricPFQ` is introduced in _v3_ (1996) and the syntax doesn't change since then. The code linked in the given page doesn't even work in _v3_: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbxTP.png

Comment: Aha, this is asked before: [What kind of hypergeometric function is it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25680/what-kind-of-hypergeometric-function-is-it)

Comment: @xzczd Oh wow, thank you! What a monstrocity.

Answer (score 0):

Extended comment:  In the `Details` section of `HypergeometricPFQ` for *Mathematica* 12.1 is

[image: Definition of HypergeometricPFQ]

You seem to think that the right-hand side of the following equation

[image: Symbolic definition]

represents *Mathematica* code (with the two z's).  It is not and never was.

Comment: Please read the question properly. The function in question is *not* ``HypergeometricPFQ'', defined as you have written. It is written differently in mathematical form (see the form $F^{abc}_{def}$). The documentation I have linked to uses the symbol `HypergeometricFPQ` but has a different number of inputs. Clearly in some old deprecated version of Mathematica whatever function it is overloaded the same function name with a different number of inputs.

Comment: I have read it properly.  You say "`HypergeometricPFQ[{{1 + a, 1 + b}, {1}, {1, b}}, {{2, 1 + c}, {}, {1 + b}}, z, z]` 

I cannot find the definition of such a function anywhere. Moreover, when I attempt to input said function into Mathematica (version 12) it doesn't recognise the input giving error".  I simply showed you what the documentation says that you say you can't find.  Also, *Mathematica* is telling you that you gave it 4 arguments when it only takes 3.  It means what it says.

Comment: There is an explicit description of said function $2^{212}_{201}$ and its input is explicitly described in Mathematica code on that webpage. I understand it must be deprecated.  Unlike what your edit implies, *I* don't think it is Mathematica code, I'm just directly followed the webpage. I *know* its not valid current Mathematica code - I said as much in my original post. So: given that you have now written the function I am asking about: what is that function on the r.h.s.? How do I input it in Mathematica? That page *does* say to use HypergeometricPFQ. Look at the section "input form"

Comment: It appears to be a two-variable hypergeometric function somewhat related to `AppellF1`.

Comment: I didn't "write" the function.  I just copied the picture from the link you provided.